# Using dynamic jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this, css-selectors

I'm fairly new to jQuery and want to move past using explicit selectors and muddying up my code this way. I have tried a few different things but am unsuccessful at getting my selectors to dynamically function on multiple elements without having a snippet of code for each element.

My script is simply as follows:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {


            $("#navItem").mouseenter(function(){

                $(this).animate({
                    height: "150px"
                }, 500, "easeOutBounce")
            })

            $("#navItem").mouseleave(function(){

                $(this).animate({
                    height: "120px"
                }, 500, "easeOutBounce")
            })
    </script>
```

And my HTML..

```
<div class="navWrap">

     <div id="navItem" class="navButton blue"></div>
     <div id="navItem2" class="navButton orange"></div>
     <div id="navItem3" class="navButton green"></div>
     <div id="navItem4" class="navButton red"></div>


</div>
```

I left out the remainder of the script because it's repetitive (the same functions for the rest of the IDs you see in the HTML). My goal is to be able to dynamically select the "current" element that is being hovered over, rather than explicitly referencing each ID. I assume I need to use the "this" selector, but the documentation I've found I have trouble relating back to my scenario.

Any help is appreciated, thanks all!

Comment: @Fresheyeball - Hi and thank you, this seemed to work best and was most comprehensible to me. Now, to further my code, I'd like to add some link text inside the divs, and animate that as well (separately, though) - how would I go about referencing the <p> tags I have (they are children of my divs. I've tried a few things already, I can get it to animate ALL the <p> in each <div> simultaneously but obviously that it not what I want... my code is simply `<a><div><p></p></div></a>` essentially for each tab I have, each needing to animate separately. Everything is classed and Id-ed.. thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.navButton').hover(function(){
         $(this).animate({
                height: "150px"
            }, 500, "easeOutBounce");
},function(){
          $(this).animate({
                height: "120px"
            }, 500, "easeOutBounce")
});
```

selectors in jquery are basically the same as css selectors, so selecting by class will make a jquery object containing all elements with that class. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

When you apply a jquery function typically `$(this)` refers to a single specific element in question rather than the entire list, so use $(this) to effect elements selected by class will work fine. I you need multiple bindings to a group you should check out `.each` http://api.jquery.com/each/

I am using .hover here which is a shorthand for mouseenter and mouseleave http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Hi thank you, this seemed to work best and was most comprehensible to me. Now, to further my code, I'd like to add some link text inside the divs, and animate that as well (separately, though) - how would I go about referencing the <p> tags I have (they are children of my divs. I've tried a few things already, I can get it to animate ALL the <p> in each <div> simultaneously but obviously that it not what I want... my HTML looks like this:

Comment: If my answer worked for you please hit the checkmark next to my answer.  To reference child `p` tags try the `.children` function. `$(this).children('p').animate`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.navButton').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
            $(this).animate({
                height: e.type == "mouseenter" ? 150 : 120
            }, 500, "easeOutBounce")
        });
    });
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $navItems = $('.navitem');

        $navitems.each( function(){
            $(this).mouseenter(function(){

                $(this).animate({
                    height: "150px"
                }, 500, "easeOutBounce")
            })

            $(this).mouseleave(function(){

                $(this).animate({
                    height: "120px"
                }, 500, "easeOutBounce")
        });
    })
</script>
```

and html like this

```
<div class="navWrap">

     <div id="navItem" class="navButton blue"></div>
     <div id="navItem" class="navButton orange"></div>
     <div id="navItem" class="navButton green"></div>
     <div id="navItem" class="navButton red"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the answers...it looks like everyone's code contributions work great! Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, you could condense the code to:

```
$(".navWrap .navButton").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: "150px"
    }, 500, "easeOutBounce")
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: "120px"
    }, 500, "easeOutBounce")
})​;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {


            $("div[id^='navItem']").mouseenter(function(){

                $(this).animate({
                    height: "150px"
                }, 500, "easeOutBounce")
            })

            $("div[id^='navItem']").mouseleave(function(){

                $(this).animate({
                    height: "120px"
                }, 500, "easeOutBounce")
            })
    </script>
```

Comment: Massively inefficient use of selectors dude.